# How to drag and drop in Cypress.io

Tags: javascript, testing, drag-and-drop, e2e-testing, cypress

I am testing Trello and trying to drag the last list and then drop it into a penultimate column, but the test is not working without ".wait". It would be really helpful if someone could advise about the potential issue here because I prefer to avoid using ".wait". There are no errors throwing, but still, the drag and drop is not happening without ".wait".

```py
describe("Moving list", () => {
  it("Waiting For Accept list should be moved from last column to the penultimate column", () => {
    cy.get("#board")
      .children(".js-list")
      .should("have.length", 4)
      .and("be.visible");

    cy.get(":nth-child(4) > .list")
      .should("be.visible")
      .and("contain", "Waiting For Accept")

    cy.get(":nth-child(4) > .list").trigger("mousedown", {
      which: 1
    });

    cy.get("#board > div:nth-child(2) > .list")
      .trigger("mousemove");

    cy.get("#board > div:nth-child(3) > .list")
      .trigger("mousemove")
      .trigger("mouseup");

    cy.get(":nth-child(3) > .list")
      .should("contain", "Waiting For Accept");
  });
});
```

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFwrV.jpg)

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c3ha.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved this issue by using "cy.request"

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html#Syntax

```
describe("Moving list", () => {
        it("Waiting For Accept list should be moved from last column to the penultimate column", () => {
            cy.request("https://trello.com/b/9lfzKIRu/trello-tests").then(response => {
                expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
            });
            cy.get("#board > div:nth-child(4) > .list").trigger("mousedown", {
                which: 1
            });
            cy.get("#board > div:nth-child(2) > .list").trigger("mousemove");
            cy.get("#board > div:nth-child(3) > .list")
                .trigger("mousemove")
                .trigger("mouseup");
            cy.get(":nth-child(3) > .list").should("contain", "Waiting For Accept");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't work out of the box, the logged issue for that is https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/845 . But in that same ticket is also a work around available using the native drag and drop API with draggable attribute on draggable elements:

**Create a custom command**

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("dragTo", { prevSubject: "element" }, (subject, targetEl) => {
    cy.wrap(subject).trigger("dragstart");
    cy.get(targetEl).trigger("drop");
  }
);
```

**In the testscript you can use:**

```js
cy.get(".source").dragTo(".target");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Cypress drap and drop plugin

https://github.com/4teamwork/cypress-drag-drop

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to use  https://github.com/4teamwork/cypress-drag-drop it supports dragging to top and bottom too.

```
        cy.get('#placeholder-3').drag('#placeholder-2', {            position: 'top', })
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by downgrading my drag and drop version from 2.1.0 to 1.8.0

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@4tw/cypress-drag-drop